# django tutorial missbehaviour

Tags: python, django

The 3 lines with

```
was_published_recently
```

Are not working, when i display the adminPoll nothing happens

django 1.6.5, python 2.7.6 ubuntu 14.04

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    # ...
    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    was_published_recently.admin_order_field = 'pub_date'
    was_published_recently.boolean = True
    was_published_recently.short_description = 'Published recently?'
```

Any help ?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What do you mean by "nothing happens"?

Comment: SOrry, when i say nothing happens  i mean the browser doesn't show what is supposed to do following the django tutorial, the header of the list must change to "Published recently?" and i must be able to sort it by "pub_date"

Answer (score 0):

che if you add was_published_recently to list_display :

```
class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
# ...
    list_display = ('question_text', 'pub_date', 'was_published_recently')
```